# How do CMSs like WordPress create/serve pages on the fly?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am working on a small project where I'll have to handle hundreds of pages, each with a similar structure but different internal content.

My first idea was to write a program that would write/edit the pages as needed, so I would actually have a folder with page1.php, page2.php, page3.php and so on.

I figured it would probably be easier to store the content of each page on a database, and them to create them on the fly, pretty much like WordPress and other CMSs do.

**Question**: Problem is I am not sure how to handle the requests. For instance, when someone tries to access mydomain.com/page1.php, I won't have an actual page called page1.php, so how do I respond to that request with the appropriate content? I know how to get the stuff from the database and structure it, but what will trigger that event?

I just need a general guidance, like if I should do it with .htaccess, with PHP, and so on. Once I get the big picture I'll research more and learn to do it.

Thanks

Comment: just use something like mydomain.com/?page=page1, and in the server side have some logic that loads the correct page from db. Then you can use htaccess or similar to prettify the url to something like mydomain.com/page1.html or whatever.

Comment: So basically use .htaccess to prettify the URLs, and once requests come convert them to my root domain plus GET parameters to specify the page?

Comment: That's one (pretty normal) way of doing it, yes :)